# Check port usage at runtime?

Tags: java, sockets, port

In my application, during runtime, I would like to be able to identify if a particular port is being used (pretty easy to do this)

```
public static boolean portAvailable(int port) {
    try (Socket ignored = new Socket("localhost", port)) {
        return false;
    } catch (IOException ignored) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

but I would also like to get as much information as possible about who is using this port. Stuff like process id, name etc. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: `windows` or `*nix` platform?

Comment: Ideally I can support both, but *nix is the minimum requirement

Answer (score 1):

Java does not provide the information you are looking for.  You will have to use OS-specific APIs instead.

I don't know about *nix systems, but on Windows you can get the owning process ID for a TCP socket by using [`GetTcpTable2()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb408406.aspx)/[`GetTcp6Table2()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb408405.aspx) or [`GetExtendedTcpTable()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365928.aspx) to enumerate TCP sockets until you find the IP/Port you are interested in.  For UDP, there is a [`GetExtendedUdpTable()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365930.aspx) function (and there are also `GetUdpTable()` and `GetUdp6Table()` functions, but they do not provide owner process IDs).

Once you have a process ID, you can get its filename by either:

1. using [`CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682489.aspx)/[`Process32First()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684834.aspx)/[`Process32Next()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684836.aspx) to enumerate running processes until you find a matching process ID.
2. using [`OpenProcess()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320.aspx) to directly open the process of a given process ID, and then query that process's filename using [`GetModuleFileNameEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683198.aspx), [`GetProcessImageFileName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683217.aspx), or [`QueryFullProcessImageName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684919.aspx).